# simpler question from sylvesters eqn

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

i think i can simplify my problem from sylvesters
equation (AX - XB = C) to this:

(D_1) X - X(D_2) = 0

where

D_1 is diagonal nxn

D_2 is diagonal mxm

X is nxm

D and D_2 are diagonal matrices
and they share at least one (eigen)value.
so the solution is not unique, but i want
to find the 'best' one, although i am not sure
about how to measure that.

pointers,links,corrected names,etc are all appreciated

Comment: It's impossible to answer unless you provide more information on what you mean by 'best'. Do you have an application in mind? What are you going to use $X$ for? Another function of $X$ that you want to minimize?